# how to update my linq to sql setup when db changes?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I changed my db model, now I need to update my linq setup.  How do I do that?

btw, I renamed all the databases in the designer so I can't just drag and drop it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built in support for this, but have a look at [Huagati DBML tools](http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/). I tried this when it was in an early version, and it seemed to work pretty well.